# Why does "{1: 'a', True: 'b', 1.0: 'c', 1.00: 'd'}" evaluate to "{1: 'd'}"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, expression

When I enter the expression `{1: 'a', True: 'b', 1.0: 'c', 1.00: 'd'}` into the Python shell, I get back `{1: 'd'}`. But when I write `{1: 'a', True: 'b', 1.0: 'c', 1.00: 'd'} [True]`, the interpreter returns me `'d'`. I don't understand how this dictionary evaluation works.

Comment: the keys of the dictionaries must be unique, if you use the same key only the last one will remain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python uses the same equality test that the `==` operator uses.  All of the keys you're using (`1`, `True`, `1.0`, and `1.00`) compare as equal to each other.  What's happening with your dicts is it's retaining the first key, then updating the value associated with that key for all subsequent keys that compare as equal to it.  It's a bit unintuitive, since the key values are not the same (except for `1.0` and `1.00`), but they are "equal".

Similarly, `{1: 'd'}[True]` evaluates to `'d'` because `True == 1`.

Comment: Oh thanks! I was really confused about this when I added mixed values to my dictionary because I was parsing a csv file. I got it down to `{1: 'a', True: 'b', 1.0: 'c', 1.00: 'd'}`.

Answer (score 1):

All of the values 1, True, 1.0 and 1.00 are equal (1.0 and 1.00 are the exact same value).  So they are all considered the same key in the dictionary.  You can't have a dict with multiple equal keys.

Answer (score 1):

**Python doesn't support duplicate keys in a dictionary.**

In the example, all the keys are same (`True==1` evaluates to `True`).
So Python will discard every key-value except the last one.